# calculate IDF from scratch

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, tf-idf

I am trying to calculate the IDF values from scratch so I can understand how it works behind the scene but still couldn't get the expected results.

I have a set of documents like this

```
docs = {'d1' :'t3 t3 t3 t6 t6', 
        'd2' :'t1 t2 t3 t3 t6', 
        'd3' :'t3 t3 t4 t5', 
        'd4' :'t4 t5 t6 t6', 
        'd5' :'t1 t2 t3 t5'}
```

and I am supposed to calculate a value called `query_sum_idf` that represents the sum value of IDF for the tokens sent in request which is in this case `['t5', 't2']`

The expected value in this case is `1.4271 ± 1.0e-04`, but when developing the calculus, here is what I did and I got different results :
`math.log10(5 / float(3)) + math.log10(5 / float(2)) = 0.6197`, where `5` is the total number of documents and `3` is the count of `t5`in all the documents and last `2`is the count of `t2` in all the documents.

As you can see the results are different, so I'm asking if I'm missing something around.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem you have there.

I have tried to do this task on my own, and looked up common definitions of IDF on wikipedia. I calculate IDF like this:

```
import math
def idf(docs, term):
    count = 0
    for key, doc in docs.items():
        if term in doc: count += 1
    return math.log(len(docs)/count)
```

**The issue is, you are using log10 instead of natural logarithm.** Even on wiki, it is not defined, which `log` to use. I hope I helped.